# Структура темы Wordpress. Landing page

Tags: wordpress

Ребят, верстаю лендинг на вордпресс. Вопрос по структуре темы.
Допустим у меня будет осн страница fontend-page.php и в ней для каждого section будет запрос.

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', slider); ?> <!--slider-->

<?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', about_us); ?> <!--about us-->

<?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', latest_news); ?> <!--latest news-->

<?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', testimonials); ?> <!--testimonials-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Вопрос в том, как сделать максимально правильно? И также что прописывать в index.php? Стандартный цикл вордпресс?
Сам макет:
[image: Макет]

Comment: По моему вы все классно и правильно сделали :)

Comment: Посмотри как это сделано в разных темах из оф каталога(это важно! только там проверенные темы). Только выбирай темы без конструкторов! Мне напр нравится когда секции заполняются виджетами. Но есть и др способы. Твой вариант тоже имеет место быть, но всё равно темпелйты должны содержать не конечный контент, а интерфейс настройки (виджеты или настойки из кастомайзера или ещё что), так что большого смысла так делать я лично не вижу. По поводу индекса см для начала https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @SeVlad решил делать через page template + acf, то есть ты выбираешь шаблон страницы(landing page) к которому подвязаны собственно все поля с acf которые нужно заполнить  картинки галереи и тд. На сколько этот вариант жизнеспособен?)

Comment: Костыль на костыле как по мне. Зачем ещё acf.. Есть же родные средсва.